# Ant D Drawer , mask={false} and maskClosable={true} incompatible?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using the ant d Drawer component as a pop up modal. I wanted to disable the mask as I didnt want the dark mask it applies to the left hand side, however this seems to prevent the component from mantaining its mask closable parameter which allows you to close the modal by clicking on the left side of the screen (mask)

A possible solution would be to mantain the mask param as true but change the css styling so its completely transparent but I am not sure how to do this?

Any other solutions are welcomed

Thanks in advance

```
<div>
  <Drawer
    className="add-days-modal"
    placement="right"
    closable={false}
    onClose={props.handleCancel}
    visible={props.addDayModalVisible}
    key="right"
    width="500px"
    maskClosable={true}
    mask={false}
  >
    {props.content}
  </Drawer>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide an reproducible example using codesandbox

Answer (score 1):

Without the mask there is nothing for the user to click on which would trigger the close event.

What you can try doing instead to achieve what you are after is set the opacity on the mask to 0, this will mean that it is invisible to the user but they can still click on it which will close the Drawer.

The other option which is much more complex is to add an event handler to the screen click. Then when the user clicks anywhere away from the draw you set the state of the Drawer to closed.

My advice is go with option 1